# SQL Server Modulus and user defined function

Tags: sql

I'm using Modulus % inside a function and its not behaving as I'd expect:

```
drop function af_EmployeeName
go

Create function [dbo].[af_EmployeeName]    
(  
@ParamName VARCHAR(512)
, @ParamRef1 VARCHAR(64)
, @ParamRef2 VARCHAR(64)
, @ParamRef3 VARCHAR(64)
, @ParamRef VARCHAR(64)
, @ParamNI VARCHAR(64)
, @ParamIsEmplRef INT
)  
RETURNS VARCHAR(1100)
AS 
BEGIN  

RETURN  

COALESCE(@ParamName, '')

+ CASE 
    WHEN @ParamIsEmplRef <> 0 THEN
        ': '
    ELSE
        ''
    END

+ CASE 
    WHEN @ParamIsEmplRef&2 <> 0  THEN --1
        COALESCE(@ParamRef1 , '') + ', '
    ELSE
        ''
    END
 END

GO

SELECT dbo.af_EmployeeName('Name','ref1','ref2','ref3', 'payref', 'ni', 0) [0]
    , dbo.af_EmployeeName('Name','ref1','ref2','ref3', 'payref', 'ni', 1) [1]
    , dbo.af_EmployeeName('Name','ref1','ref2','ref3', 'payref', 'ni', 2) [2]
```

What I get is

0   1   2
Name    Name:   Name: ref1,

Waht I expect is

0   1       2
Name    Name: ref1, Name: ref2,

on the basis of

```
SELECT 0%2 [0],  1%2 [1], 2%2 [2]
```

giving

0   1   2
0   1   0

Please put me out of my misery....

Comment: You have bitwise & - @ParamIsEmplRef & 2 ... not modulus

Comment: Dhhooo, and they are celibrating 500 shows. thanks Alex - i'd have accepted an answere too...

Answer (score 0):

this was a typo, which I had looked at over the best part of a day....